# synchronized block not locking the object reference

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

```
class Demo
{
    void demo()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside demo of "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException exc)
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" interrupted");
        }
    }
}

class MyThread1 implements Runnable
{
    Thread thread;
    Demo d;

    MyThread1(String name, Demo ob)
    {
        d = ob;
        thread = new Thread(this, name);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println(thread.getName()+" starting");

        synchronized(d)
        {
            d.demo();
        }

        System.out.println(thread.getName()+" ending");
    }
}

class MyThread2 implements Runnable
{
    Thread thread;
    Demo d;

    MyThread2(String name, Demo ob)
    {
        d = ob;
        thread = new Thread(this, name);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    { 
       System.out.println(thread.getName()+" starting");

       d.demo();

       System.out.println(thread.getName()+" ending");
    }
}

class TimePass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Demo d = new Demo();

        MyThread1 mt1 = new MyThread1("Thread 1", d);
        MyThread2 mt2 = new MyThread2("Thread 2", d);
    }
}
```

The output is

> Thread 1 starting
>
> Inside demo of Thread 1
>
> Thread 2 starting
>
> Inside demo of Thread 2

Due to `Thread.sleep(1000000)`, the execution is not yet ended.

I have passed the same instance of class `Demo` to both the constructors of classes `MyThread1` and `MyThread2`.

```
Demo d = new Demo();
MyThread1 mt1 = new MyThread1("Thread 1", d);
MyThread2 mt2 = new MyThread2("Thread 2", d);
```

The call to `d.demo` in `MyThread1` is in a `synchronized` block.
The call to `d.demo` in `MyThread2` is *not* in a `synchronized` block.

So, when `MyThread1` is executing, due to the `synchronized` block, the monitor of `d` should be locked, resulting in denial of access to `d.demo()` by the `MyThread2`.

*But this is not happening.*

The expected output is

```
Thread 1 starting
Inside demo of Thread1
Thread 2 starting
```

(The output is before `Thread.sleep(1000000)` is finished.)

So, my basic question is: **How `MyThread2.d.demo()` is executing successfully even if `MyThread1.d.demo()` is not yet finished the `synchronized` block?**

Comment: "the monitor of d should be locked, resulting in denial of access to d.demo() by the MyThread2" - **this is a false statement**. You need to use `synchronized` in MyThread2 as well.

Comment: `resulting in denial of access to d.demo() by the MyThread2.` no. There is nothing to prevent MyThread2 to access `d.demo`. `d.demo` is not synchronized. The block in thread1 is. If you create 2 `Thread1`,  you'll see the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, when MyThread1 is executing, due to the `synchronized` block, the monitor of `d` should be locked, resulting in denial of access to `d.demo()` by the MyThread2.

That would only happen if MyThread2 also had a `synchronized` block. When one thread is synchronized on an object, other threads will be blocked if they also try to synchronize on that same object. If they don't synchronize, they won't be. There's nothing that stops access to an object from threads that don't synchronize on it.

Synchronization is a **cooperative** mechanism. It only works when all threads work together.

Answer (score 3):

The `synchronization` only occurs in `Thread1`.  Since `Thread2` does not `synchronize` on `d`, it is allowed to invoke `demo()` while Thread1 holds the lock.

You seem to be misunderstanding the use of `synchronized`.  Synchronization only occurs with other threads trying to enter a synchronized block of the common object.

Answer (score 3):

Synchronization is a collaborative effort. Each party states that when another party is in a critical section, they won't be.

You've only `synchronized` access to the `demo` method of the `Demo` instance in one thread

```
synchronized(d)
{
    d.demo();
}
```

The other is accessing it directly

```
d.demo();
```

They've broken these collaboration rules so you can't assume anything.

This is explained in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19)

> **Acquiring the lock associated with an object does not in itself
>   prevent other threads from accessing fields of the object or invoking
>   un-synchronized methods on the object.** Other threads can also use
>   synchronized methods or the synchronized statement in a conventional
>   manner to achieve mutual exclusion.